# Using event delegation on JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good day.

I don't know the right terminology about my question but what I want to ask is how to ask is this:

```
//functionA
$(document).on('click', '.classA1, .classA2, .classA3', function(event) {
    //i want to call the functionB when functionA is used.
    //if possible, when I use the onclick on classB2

}

//functionB
$(document).on('click', '.classB1, .classB2', function(event) {}
```

note, I am new to JavaScript and was suddenly given a task by my boss. I cant really ask them about this since they are also new to the project/JavaScript since we just received the project from previous developer.

Comment: The correct terminology is `event delegation`

Comment: you can add more elements to 2 nd param of on() like this : 
$(document).on('click', '.classA1, .classA2, .classA3,.classB1, .classB2', function(event) {
}

Comment: You can use either use suggestion by @jpo or call `$('.classB2').trigger('click')` at the end of functionA.

Comment: Also, if you find an answer useful, please mark it as the correct answer, so that this can be helpful for others :)

Answer (score 0):

If I would be thinking simply about it, I would declare two methods first and then use them as callbacks in the listeners.

```
function functionA(event) {
   // implement your logic here

   // and call functionB as well
   functionB(event);
} 

function functionB(event) {
  // implement your B logic here
}

$(document).on('click', '.classA1, .classA2, .classA3', functionA);
$(document).on('click', '.classB1, .classB2', functionB);
```

This is actually not much else to be done as you can't delegate an event in such way as you wish it.

Imagine following scenario. Pink rectangle would be e.g. a span within a div (black rectangle) If you would add a click listener to the "div", then the click event would fire when you click the "div" and even if you click the "span". The click event propagated.

[image]

Otherwise you might want to add multiple click listeners to the same object. Then depending on your desire you can either interrupt the propagation (blocking the other listeners) by e.g. invoking the `event.stopPropagation()` method.

I would like the community to add more explanations if I missed something critical.

Comment: tried to do this flow earlier but It failed. because I did something wrong with my version. will try this one

Comment: As this is almost "vanilla" javascript, there is not much which can go wrong or what could depend on a version. Let us know if it helped you :)

Comment: this answered my question. unfortunately not the right code that I need in my work.thanks @jPO

Comment: I understand you. Yet what you want to achieve is possible only this way. If you want like to delegate any event, then you must make sure, that all observers listen to the same event. And the same event can only come from the same object. Only in this case we can be talking about delegation. Imagine a span within a div. If you add onclick listener to the div, then the click event fires even if the span was clicked. That is an example of delegation. I will update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.classA1, .classA2, .classA3').on('click', ()=> {
  console.log('function A called');
  $('.classB1, .classB2').trigger('click');
});
$('.classB1, .classB2').on('click', ()=> {
  console.log('function B called');
});
```

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  background: teal;
  padding: .5rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  font: 16px Arial, sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.b {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="classA1">class A1</a>
<a class="classA2">class A2</a>
<a class="classA3">class A3</a>

<a class="classB1 b">class B1</a>
<a class="classB2 b">class B2</a>
```

Comment: the answer of @jPO works. but not the right code that I needed. thanks for the help

Comment: I changed the code in my answer. It does exactly the same but using jQuery trigger function. Maybe that's what you are looking for?

Comment: no. what i mean is the answer that i am looking for is on a different function/part of the code not this one. thank you for the comment/answer guys!

Comment: these answers posted here answered my intended question.